# JNI in Windows not registering function

Tags: java, c++, dll, java-native-interface, 64-bit

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:     dlltestproject.DLLTestProject.inDll()V
    at dlltestproject.DLLTestProject.inDll(Native Method)
    at dlltestproject.DLLTestProject.main(DLLTestProject.java:22)
Java Result: 1
```

I'm trying to run JNI to call a DLL built in VS 2010 Express on a W7 X64 machine, but I always get the above error. (Note : DLLTestProject.java/.class is under the package dlltestproject

Source code :

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package dlltestproject;

/**
 *
 * @author Arhowk
 */
public class DLLTestProject {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    static{
        System.loadLibrary("NewDLLTest");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.home"));
       DLLTestProject t = new DLLTestProject();
       t.inDll();
    }
    public native void inDll();
}
```

DLL Header  :

```
    /* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class dlltestproject_DLLTestProject */

#ifndef _Included_dlltestproject_DLLTestProject
#define _Included_dlltestproject_DLLTestProject
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     dlltestproject_DLLTestProject
 * Method:    inDll
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_dlltestproject_DLLTestProject_inDll
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

DLL Source :

```
// NewDLLTest.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "NewDLLTest.h"
#include <jni.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Winuser.h>
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_dlltestproject_DLLTestProject_inDll(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
    int msgboxID = MessageBox(
        NULL,
        (LPCWSTR)L"Resource not available\nDo you want to try again?",
        (LPCWSTR)L"Account Details",
        MB_ICONWARNING | MB_CANCELTRYCONTINUE | MB_DEFBUTTON2
    );
};
```

Comment: Why are there two headers? The declaration in the second header should be inside the `extern "C" {}` block in the first one. And you don't need to include `jni.h` twice.

Comment: I realized this a little while ago, but recompiling it with the merged headers didn't help. Updated OP headers

Comment: I've been looking through every google entry and I can't find any solution that works. A couple I've found said to not use VS2010 and instead use the Windows compiler, but I can't find any documentation on Windows compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

For anyone that would like to know, the issue was the move of the javah-compiled header file to the project. I had to manually go into the VS2010 studio project and put in the header file (rather than copy pasting it in the editor) than include it in the main .cpp file